# $A$ and $X$ $n \times n$ real matrices. Find the dimension of subspace $A^TX = -X^TA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

**Problem**: Let $X$ be a matrix where $x_{ij}$ are all variables. $A$ is invertible and both matrices are real and $n \times n$. What is the dimension of the subspace of X satisfying the equation: $A^TX + X^TA = 0$

**What I did**: $A^TX = M$, then

$M^t = X^TA$ so $M = -M^T$
There, I found out that $m_{ij} = -m_{ji}$ and $m_{ii} = 0$

Therefore, if $X_{i}$ are the columns of $X$ and $A_{i}$ the columns of $A$;

$(A_{i}\cdot X_{j}) = m_{ij}$ and then:

$(A_{i}\cdot X_{j}) + (A_{j}\cdot X_{i}) = 0$

Giving me $(n^2 + n)/2$ and $n^2$ variables

**Question**: How can I find the dimension? My guess is that **every equation** is **independent**, so the dimension would be $(n^2-n)/2$, but I was not able to prove this fact so far.

Comment: is $t$ transpose?

Comment: Yes, @AjayMishra . Changed to T instead of t, thanks.

Comment: Edit it to be $T$ rather than $t$, just for convenience,as former is widely accepted notation.

Comment: I take it $A$ is given, and you are asking for the dimension of the space of all $X$ satisfying the equation.

Comment: You have found that $M$ is skew-symmetric, and it is well-known that the dimension of the space of skew-symmetric matrices is $(n^2-n)/2$, so you've got the right answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson,exactly, dimension of the space of all X satisfying the equation. I understand that the dimension of M is that, but for me this problem it's not the same as X = M, M skew-symmetric.

Comment: But it is the same dimension, since $X=(A^t)^{-1}M$ gives an isomorphism between the space of $M$s and the space of $X$s.